Why ack don't ignore assets/js/webpack.js file?
I am using ubuntu.
Ack version
ack v3.7.0 (standard build)
Ignored files from ~/.ackrc dont is not ignored
In file ~/.ackrc write this code
--ignore-file=is:dist/main-hash.css
--ignore-file=is:assets/js/webpack.js

In project where have webpack.js file
❯ find . -name "webpack.js"
./assets/js/webpack.js

Want to find some word
ack ".categories-list" | less

template-parts/taxonomy-page-sidebar.php:43:                            <ul class="categories-list__chld">
assets/js/webpack.js:157:eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony import */ var _modules_animation_accordion_animation__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./modules/animation/accordion-animation */ \"./src/js/modules/animation/accordion-animation.js\");\n/* harmony import */ var _modules_animation_features_works_animation__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./mod

The file webpack.js is not ignored.

Wat ack version are you using?

ack v3.7.0 (standard build)

The pattern also isn't in the webpack.js line. Something very weird is going on.

Did you ever get an answer to this? If not, maybe file a ticket at github.com/beyondgrep/ack3.
